# Do we need to use XMLHTTPRequest when we use Ajax?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am new to Ajax.I found that Ajax will use XMLHTTPRequest. Can any one clarify me the usage of XMLHttpRequest without Ajax and with Ajax with an example.?

How asynchrnous Postback will occur ?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 1):

XMLHTTPRequest is the underlying browser feature that makes what we call AJAX possible, you cannot have one without the other. Postback sounds like a reference to a .Net, which is a completely separate technology to AJAX/XMLHTTPRequest.

[Find out more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)